# What's the most pythonic way (if any) to refactor these nested for/else loops?

Tags: python, for-loop, coding-style, refactoring, nested-loops

I have a function which checks for substrings in a string. Depending on the type of substring found in the string, I call a unique function and store it in variable `x`. At the end, the function has a standardized return which does several complicated operations to `x` and then returns it. Like so:

```
def awesome(string):
    for substring in ['AB', 'CD', 'EF']:
        if substring in string:
            x = do_something()
            break
    else:
        for substring in ['12', '34', '56']:
            if substring in string:
                x = do_something_else()
                break
        else:
            for substring in ['!@', '@#', '#$']:
                if substring in string:
                    x = do_another_thing()
                    break
    # Universally modifies x
    x += complicated_thing()
    if some_condition(x):
        x += "Hello"
    else:
        x += "World"
    return x
```

Three choices are initially obvious to me:

- The first is to leave it as-is. The nested for/else loops, of course, are a bit ugly.
- The second option is to include the code block that universally modifies `x` and `return`s in each `for` loop instead of `break`, but that seems to ruin the principle of Don't Repeat Yourself.
- Finally, I could save the final code block in a new function `function` and return `function(x)` in each for loop, but does that create an unnecessarily esoteric function that has very little use?

Any advice is appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: What is the default value of `x` (if none of the if blocks are executed)? Also, why not do `for substring in 'ABC'` instead of `for substring in ['A', 'B', 'C']`?

Comment: In my program, one of the blocks is always executed. There's an error somewhere else in the program if `x` is never assigned.

Also, the strings are more than one character. I edited the question to reflect that.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about a code review and not a real problem!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
def is_substr(input_string, substrs):
    return any(strs in input_string for strs in substrs)

def awesome(my_string):
    if is_substr(my_string, ["A", "B", "C"]):
        x = do_something() + complicated_thing()
    elif is_substr(my_string, ["1", "2", "3"]):
        x = do_something_else() + complicated_thing()
    elif is_substr(my_string, ["!", "#", "$"]):
        x = do_another_thing() + complicated_thing()
    return x + ("Hello" if some_condition(x) else "World")
```

**If the order of the checks doesn't matter**, this can be further generalized and squeezed like this

```
def awesome(input_string):
    functions_dict = {
        ('AB', 'CD', 'EF'): do_something,
        ('12', '34', '56'): do_something_else,
        ('!@', '@#', '#$'): do_another_thing
    }
    for sub_strings, function in functions_dict.items():
        if any(s in input_string for s in sub_strings):
            x = function() + complicated_thing()
            return x + ("Hello" if some_condition(x) else "World")
```

Comment: Downvoter, please let me know what is wrong with this solution.

Comment: I think I'm going to go with this one. Thanks.

Comment: @thefourtheye The second version here doesn't take care of the order of the checks. If both 'AB' and '12' is in `string`, `do_something` should be called, not `do_something_else`, and you can't know the order of the returned items when using a dict.

Comment: @SteinarLima Indeed, but the OP hasn't mentioned anything about the order, right? I ll put a note anyway

Answer (score 4):

How about this:

```
def check(substrings, somestring):
    return any(substring in somestring for substring in substrings)

def awesome(somestring):
    x = some_default_value
    vals = [do_something, do_something_else, do_another_thing]
    subs = [['AB', 'CD', 'EF'], ['12', '34', '56'], ['!@', '@#', '#$']]
    for val,substrings in zip(vals, subs):
        if check(substrings, somestring):
            x = val()
            break

    # Universally modifies x
    x += complicated_thing()
    if some_condition(x):
        x += "Hello"
    else:
        x += "World"
    return x
```

Answer (score 3):

This should also work.

```
def awesome(string):

    foo = [{'subs': ['A', 'B', 'C'], 'func': do_something},
           {'subs': ['1', '2', '3'], 'func': do_something_else},
           {'subs': ['!', '?', '.'], 'func': do_another_thing}
    ]

    for bar in foo:
        if any(s in string for s in bar['subs']):
            x = bar['func']()
            break

    # Universally modifies x
    x += complicated_thing()
    if some_condition(x):
        x += "Hello"
    else:
        x += "World"
    return x
```

Comment: You know what, I was coding the exact same idea in my sublime now ;)

Comment: @thefourtheye Not with an dictionary. They are not ordered.

Comment: But the dicts could (should?) be tuples perhaps.

Comment: Why not use `namedtuple`s here? They're lighter and faster than `dict`s and you could use the `.` syntax, as opposed to the messy string-key syntax

Comment: @SteinarLima Please check my version of the same idea :)

Comment: @inspectorG4dget I haven't encountered namedtuple before, thanks for the link :)

Comment: @thefourtheye Your code has some bugs. `items` returns a key, value pair, not all values.

Comment: @SteinarLima Yup. Thats what I want, because in my case, keys are the substrings and corresponding values are the functions to be executed :)

Answer (score 1):

A simple option would be

```
def awesome(string):
    count = 0
    for s in ['AB', 'CD', 'EF',
              '12', '34', '56',
              '!@', '@#', '#$']:
        count += 1
        if s in string:
            break

    fun = {'0': do_something, '1': do_something_else, '2': do_another_thing}

    x = fun.get(str(count / 3))() + complicated_thing()

    delta = 'Hello' if some_condition(x) else 'World'

    return x + delta
```